# Find index of element in a JSONArray

Tags: java, json, arrays

I receive a JSONObject from server that is as follows:

```
{
   "opOutput":{
      "DISPLAY_VALUES":[
         "Acceptance",
         "Arrive Load Port",
         "Arrive Receipt Point",
         "Arrive Relay Port",
         "Arrive Terminal",
         "Arrived at Delivery Location",
         "Arrived at Pickup Location",
         "Arrived Intermodal Train",
         "At Customs",
         .
         .
         .
         .  


      ],
      "VALUES":[
         "ACCPT",
         "ALPT",
         "ARRP",
         "ARREL",
         "ATRM",
         "QARD",
         "ARPUL",
         "AIMTRN",
         "K",
         .
         .
         .
         .
      ]
   },
   "_returnValue":{
      "TX_TYPE":"SHIPMENT",
      "__DeltaStatus":2,
      "ORG_CODE":"GFM",
      "TX_ID":"11019082"
   },
   "_returnType":"SUCCESS"
}
```

Now I need to get the display value for s String s that is equal to one of the values.
i.e I have string "ACCPT" and i need to get "Acceptance" from the JSONObject.

I've made two JSONArrays with DISPLAY_VALUES and VALUES
with

```
JSONObject opoutput=shipmentcodes.getJSONObject("opOutput");
JSONArray event_values=opoutput.getJSONArray("DISPLAY_VALUES");
JSONArray event_codes=opoutput.getJSONArray("VALUES");
```

where shipmentcodes is the original JSONObject, but I'm unsure about how to proceed further. Any tips?

Comment: Why can't you just iterate over the JSONArray, counting the index, and stop when you find a match?

Comment: Iterate over your VALUES array in a for loop until you find your match, and use that index to grab the right display value from DISPLAY_VALUES.

Comment: @bstar55 yeah I guess I can just do that. I thought there could be some method of JSONArray that returns the index given the element, without us going through a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the values from `JSONArray` to a `List` and use the `indexOf` method

```
JSONArray event_values = opoutput.getJSONArray("DISPLAY_VALUES");
JSONArray event_codes = opoutput.getJSONArray("VALUES");

List<String> valueList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> displayList = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<event_codes.length();i++){
        // if both event_values and event_codes are of equal length
        valueList.add(event_codes.getString(i));
        displayList.add(event_values.getString(i));
    }

int index = valueList.indexOf("ACCPT");
String valueToDisplay = displayList.get(index);
```

You can then use `valueToDisplay` for displaying the value you need.

Comment: I am trying to solve a similar problem can a take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34151997/modifying-updating-values-inside-a-jsonarray?noredirect=1#comment56051219_34151997