# Get array object if attribute value present from jsonarray

Tags: java, json

I want to get the object of jsonarray if the attribute values are matched from jsonarray. Below code is good to get the attribute value by checking the list one by one.

```
JSONParser parser1 = new JSONParser();
JSONArray array = (JSONArray)parser1.parse("[{\"user_id\": 1,\"Name\":\"Andrew\"}, {\"user_i\": 1}, {\"user\": 1}]");

 for (int i =0; i<array.size();i++){
           System.out.println(((JSONObject)array.get(i)).get("Name"));
  }
```

However, I want to get the index (list) i.e. `{\"user_id\": 1,\"Name\":\"Andrew\"}` when attribute values matches. something like

```
System.out.println(((JSONObject)array.get("Name")).get(i));
```

Can anyone please suggest me how to achieve this?

Comment: *"i want to get the index (list) ie `{\"user_id\": 1,\"Name\":\"Andrew\"}`"* An index is a number. `{\"user_id\": 1,\"Name\":\"Andrew\"}` isn't a number. What is it you're really looking for...?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what challenge you're facing but why don't you just store the result of `(JSONObject)array.get(i)` and call `get("Name")` etc. on that? If the values match your requirements you found the json object you need and can keep working with it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find index of element in a JSONArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23948955/find-index-of-element-in-a-jsonarray)

Comment: @Thomas, Due to performance issue , beacuse , i need to check a long list every time

Comment: I don't quite get your concerns about performance here. Any code that needs to find elements (or a single element) in a list that matches some properties would have to iterate over that list so there's nothing to be gained here. If the data doesn't change but you need to look for objects like this multiple times you might consider building maps instead (you might need a map per property or property combination).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you properly, you can do it with a `for` loop and `if` to get the index of the object in the array:

```
int index = -1;
for (int i = 0, len = array.size(); i < len; ++i) {
    String name = (JSONObject)array.get(i)).get("Name");
    if (name.equals("Andrew")) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}
```

There's probably some streams equivalent to that as well.

Or if you want the *object*, not its index:

```
JSONObject result = null;
for (int i = 0, len = array.size(); i < len; ++i) {
    JSONObject obj = (JSONObject)array.get(i);
    if (obj.get("Name").equals("Andrew")) {
        result = obj;
        break;
    }
}
```

or with an enhanced `for` loop:

```
JSONObject result = null;
for (Object obj : array) {
    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject)obj;
    if (jsonObj.get("Name").equals("Andrew")) {
        result = jsonObj;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Crowder,  my mistake if i am not able explain properly. What i mean i want to get the whole list '{\"user_id\": 1,\"Name\":\"Andrew\"}'   which list is having name as "Andrew"

Comment: @user3302083 I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by "list." If you  want the *object* that contains `"Name": "Andrew"`, that's the second and third examples above.